# Django editing a user generated object

Tags: ajax, django

I'm trying to figure out how to do an inline editing for a user-generated object, what the rough procedure (no code just steps), and whether or not there's some way to do this without AJAX - of course it wouldn't be "inline" anymore.

Say the user object is just 1 line of text and 1 image. Something like,

```
class UserObject(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField()
    image_path = models.CharField()
```

If I were to use AJAX, would this be how it'd go? (sorry this is vague, I can figure out the details just trying to see if I understand the concepts correctly)

1. Create a form, populate it with an instance of the object belonging to the current user
2. Next to the image, I'd have, say, a "remove" button, which triggers an AJAX call to a URL that's something like `project/remove/ab12345` that's connected to a view that handles it.
3. Wait for the AJAX call to be done
4. Then somehow remove the image and buttons, maybe by just deleting the `div` that contains it all

Is that right??

Also, what if I don't want to use AJAX? Would it go something like this?

1. Create a form, populate it with an instance of the object belonging to the current user
2. Next to the image, I'd have, say, a "remove" button, which directly links to the URL that's something like `project/remove/ab12345` that's connected to a view that handles it
3. After the view deletes the image, it goes back to the editing page, which just refreshes and the image is no longer there.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!! I can figure out the details of the coding, just wondering if I am getting the concepts right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK since I posted this ultra-vague question I'm going to answer it.

AJAX-free: 
The AJAX free version is pretty much as I described, create a view and a URL that deletes the image and goes right back to the referring page. Next going to try the AJAX version, which basically requires a view that returns some kind of a signal of failure or success.

**urls.py**

```
url('^project/remove_image/(?P<image_id_string>[0-9A-Fa-f]+)/$', pbrand.views.ProjectRemoveImageView.as_view(), name='project_remove_image'),
```

**views.py**

```
class ProjectRemoveImageView(View):
    redirect_url = '/project/edit'  # the editing url 

    def get(self, request, image_id_string, *args, **kwargs):
        # ... some checks on permissions            
        image.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.redirect_url + "/" + project.id_string)
```

**inside the template**

```
<a class = "btn btn-default btn-sm" href="{% url 'project_remove_image' i.id_string %}" role="button">remove</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

An object created by a user is really no different from one you create yourself (except you have to be suspicious of potentially malicious input!). The simplest way to be able to edit objects outside the admin interface is to use the built-in [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview). Similarly you can delete them with a [`DeleteView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview). If you want to restrict you can edit objects you can user the `PermissionRequiredMixin` from [django braces](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/v1.4.0/).

Comment: This is not what I was asking about, but really I only have myself to blame for posting an ultra-vague question =)